# JPA @JoinColumn custom object type

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I'm studying a project that uses JPA, which I'm pretty new at. I've encountered a logic that I'm not understanding quite well. I have an entity called `A` that has this field/column:

```
@Column(name = "COD_UOP_COO")
    private String codUopCoo;
```

then I have, in the same entity:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COD_UOP_COO", referencedColumnName = "COD_UOP")
    @BatchFetch(value = BatchFetchType.JOIN)
    private B b;
```

From what I understood, this means that `b` field is retrieved by joining the tables `A` and `B` on the fields specified in `JoinColumn` annotation, right? But how does the join work in this case? Is JPA retrieving an entity of the right-side of join clause?
Then I have this named query:

```
"select a from A a where (a.b.bfield = :parameter)"
```

what does this mean? Why are they checking equality on a field of entity `B`? In my table `A` I do not have any column that is foreign key with `B`. And `b` field is not a column in table `A`. So which column value of `A` am I checking? I'm missing the link with database structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPQL query is translatet to a SQL query.

This query return A objects where A.COD_UOP_COO = B.COD_UOP and B.bfield = parameter. Change bfield for the database column name of the element in the B Class.

You can see the nateive query adding this parameters to the persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Hi thank you. Is there a guide that explains the rules of translation?